# div scroll and fixed top and bottom divs (tied to x and y axis)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a chart - is created using PHP/MySQL calculation of joint life expectancy...really big.

The x and y axis for two age ranges are positioned within the container div when the page loads. I need to be able to scroll the container div (vertically and horizontally) and have the left and top containers (x and y axis) stick to the corresponding values within the chart, but also remain within the container.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top_container">X-axis: age range for person one</div>
    <div id="left_container">Y-axis: age range for person two</div>
    Content Here - overflow:hidden;
    (a huge PHP/MySQL driven chart)
</div>
```

Here is a basic idea of layout:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| X axis   - attached to content, but fixed inside main container             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Y |          main content (scroll up and down in container)                 | 
| a |                                                                         | 
| x |                                                                         |
| i |                                                                         | 
| s |                                                                         |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hopefully this makes sense...the x and y (top and left) columns need to be fixed to the main content area (so remains accurate) and need to stick to the top and left side of container area.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I figured this out...simpler than I thought but let me know if anyone has a similar question and I'll help out. Here's the basic idea:

```
$('#container_main').scroll(function(){
        $('#top_container').css({
            'top': $(this).scrollTop()
        });
        $('.row_header').css({
            'left': $(this).scrollLeft() -51 //needed tweaking for position
        });
    });
```

Positioning on the 'fixed' elements needs to be 'absolute'.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create an x-axis container div with fixed position on the top of the page. Within that fixed div, create a horizontally scrollable div with the content of your axis.

Create a y-axis container div with fixed position on the left of the page. Within that fixed div, create a vertically scrollable div with the content of your axis.

Create a content container div with fixed position. Within that fixed div, create a horizontally and vertically scrollable div.

Then, use javascript (I used jQuery but that's not required) to scroll the axes whenever the content is scrolled.

This was fun and I think it looks great! http://codepen.io/pabo/pen/KsrzJ

HTML:

```
<div id="x-axis">
    <div class="scrollablecontent">
        x-axis
        <p>
        <span class='tick'>1</span>
        <span class='tick'>2</span>
        <span class='tick'>3</span>
        <span class='tick'>4</span>
        <span class='tick'>5</span>
        <span class='tick'>6</span>
        <span class='tick'>7</span>
        <span class='tick'>8</span>
        <span class='tick'>9</span>
        <span class='tick'>10</span>
        <span class='tick'>11</span>
        <span class='tick'>12</span>
        <span class='tick'>13</span>
        <span class='tick'>14</span>
        <span class='tick'>15</span>
        <span class='tick'>16</span>
        <span class='tick'>17</span>
        <span class='tick'>18</span>
        <span class='tick'>19</span>
        <span class='tick'>20</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="y-axis">
    <div class="scrollablecontent">
        y-axis
        <span class='tick'>1</span>
        <span class='tick'>2</span>
        <span class='tick'>3</span>
        <span class='tick'>4</span>
        <span class='tick'>5</span>
        <span class='tick'>6</span>
        <span class='tick'>7</span>
        <span class='tick'>8</span>
        <span class='tick'>9</span>
        <span class='tick'>10</span>
        <span class='tick'>11</span>
        <span class='tick'>12</span>
        <span class='tick'>13</span>
        <span class='tick'>14</span>
        <span class='tick'>15</span>
        <span class='tick'>16</span>
        <span class='tick'>17</span>
        <span class='tick'>18</span>
        <span class='tick'>19</span>
        <span class='tick'>20</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="scrollablecontent"><p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef salami pork loin ham sausage. Meatball tail short loin tenderloin doner. Porchetta filet mignon hamburger, drumstick kielbasa brisket pork pancetta. Pig sirloin doner leberkas chicken, salami ham beef ribs. Pastrami rump sausage tongue cow bresaola porchetta jowl chuck kevin beef sirloin kielbasa fatback. Bacon ball tip boudin meatball drumstick, cow flank rump beef ribs pancetta. Fatback pancetta rump shank meatloaf tri-tip.

        <p>Hamburger short ribs tri-tip salami capicola. Salami jowl ribeye, strip steak spare ribs prosciutto biltong pancetta pig ball tip brisket landjaeger venison sirloin. Ham hock swine beef ribs boudin tail shoulder. Biltong kielbasa venison chuck jowl strip steak. Capicola chicken chuck, rump short ribs meatball spare ribs prosciutto. Jowl pork pork belly hamburger corned beef ground round bacon brisket kevin sirloin. Hamburger frankfurter pork belly pork filet mignon chicken fatback short ribs, rump tenderloin salami kielbasa brisket andouille bacon.

        <p>Cow turkey landjaeger biltong leberkas bresaola filet mignon shoulder hamburger. Doner sirloin boudin beef ribs shankle ham bresaola pork chop beef pork belly rump short ribs jowl leberkas. Chicken swine biltong ham hock kielbasa sirloin ball tip hamburger meatloaf pork chop turkey pork belly tongue. Brisket bresaola sausage meatloaf ground round ball tip, drumstick pancetta capicola.

        <p>Kielbasa leberkas sausage turducken landjaeger shoulder. Beef shoulder biltong prosciutto ball tip, leberkas strip steak. Ham hock salami ball tip, jowl porchetta ground round frankfurter jerky doner tenderloin short loin. Cow shankle turkey, filet mignon chuck rump kielbasa turducken. Beef jerky landjaeger leberkas pork loin pastrami tongue.

        <p>Pastrami hamburger sausage ham boudin, beef jowl kevin porchetta shank meatball landjaeger ground round pork chop kielbasa. Pig cow ground round kielbasa short loin andouille, swine shankle turducken salami venison tenderloin kevin bacon shank. Shank corned beef capicola beef jerky, landjaeger spare ribs. Ham hock biltong frankfurter pig hamburger pork tri-tip boudin pork belly bacon.

        <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef salami pork loin ham sausage. Meatball tail short loin tenderloin doner. Porchetta filet mignon hamburger, drumstick kielbasa brisket pork pancetta. Pig sirloin doner leberkas chicken, salami ham beef ribs. Pastrami rump sausage tongue cow bresaola porchetta jowl chuck kevin beef sirloin kielbasa fatback. Bacon ball tip boudin meatball drumstick, cow flank rump beef ribs pancetta. Fatback pancetta rump shank meatloaf tri-tip.

        <p>Hamburger short ribs tri-tip salami capicola. Salami jowl ribeye, strip steak spare ribs prosciutto biltong pancetta pig ball tip brisket landjaeger venison sirloin. Ham hock swine beef ribs boudin tail shoulder. Biltong kielbasa venison chuck jowl strip steak. Capicola chicken chuck, rump short ribs meatball spare ribs prosciutto. Jowl pork pork belly hamburger corned beef ground round bacon brisket kevin sirloin. Hamburger frankfurter pork belly pork filet mignon chicken fatback short ribs, rump tenderloin salami kielbasa brisket andouille bacon.

        <p>Cow turkey landjaeger biltong leberkas bresaola filet mignon shoulder hamburger. Doner sirloin boudin beef ribs shankle ham bresaola pork chop beef pork belly rump short ribs jowl leberkas. Chicken swine biltong ham hock kielbasa sirloin ball tip hamburger meatloaf pork chop turkey pork belly tongue. Brisket bresaola sausage meatloaf ground round ball tip, drumstick pancetta capicola.

        <p>Kielbasa leberkas sausage turducken landjaeger shoulder. Beef shoulder biltong prosciutto ball tip, leberkas strip steak. Ham hock salami ball tip, jowl porchetta ground round frankfurter jerky doner tenderloin short loin. Cow shankle turkey, filet mignon chuck rump kielbasa turducken. Beef jerky landjaeger leberkas pork loin pastrami tongue.

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;

  padding: 10px;

  background-color: #cc99ff;
}

#content .scrollablecontent{
    width: 2000px;
}


#x-axis {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50px;

  width: 100%;
  height: 70px; /*pushes scroll bar down, out of sight */

  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;

  background-color: #99ccff;
  text-align: center;
}

#x-axis .scrollablecontent {
  width: 2000px;
}

#x-axis .scrollablecontent .tick {
  margin-right: 75px;
}

#y-axis {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;

  height: 100%;
  width: 70px; /*pushes scroll bar right, out of sight*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;

  background-color: #99ccff;
}


#y-axis .scrollablecontent {
  height: 2000px;
}

#y-axis .scrollablecontent .tick {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 20px; /*difference between widths of y-axis and y-axis scrollable content*/
  text-align: right;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#content').on('scroll', function() {
  $('#content, #x-axis').scrollLeft($('#content').scrollLeft());
  $('#content, #y-axis').scrollTop($('#content').scrollTop());
});

$('#x-axis').on('scroll', function() {
  $('#content').scrollLeft($('#x-axis').scrollLeft());
});

$('#y-axis').on('scroll', function() {
  $('#content').scrollTop($('#y-axis').scrollTop());
});
```

Comment: Pabo - thanks for the code...I did edit my question after I figured it out, and realized I hadn't explained things as clearly as I could've. Nice clean code but I needed more functionality and needed x-axis to 'stick' to right-left scrolling as well.